# Вывод результата в столбец базы данных по результатам sql запроса

Tags: mysql

Как на основе существующей таблицы в новый столбец добавить результаты обработки?

```
SELECT c.`id` , (
  SELECT COUNT( * ) 
  FROM  `items_comments` 
  WHERE  `reply_to` = c.id
) AS сount
FROM  `items_comments` c
WHERE c.`reply_to` =0
```

Запрос исполняется, но как добавить результат в столбец?

В данном примере я создал себе в таблице `items_comments` столбец `reply_to_count`, в который должны попадать результаты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Находим все комментарии, которые сами никому не отвечают.
2. Подсчитываем, сколько ответов у каждого из них.
3. Запоминаем результат.

```sql
UPDATE `items_comments` c1
SET `reply_to_count` = 
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `items_comments` c2
WHERE c2.`reply_to` = c1.`id`)
WHERE c1.`reply_to` = 0
```